# Taylor series convergence from translation operator viewpoint

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The Taylor series of $f(x)$ about $x = 0$ is given by,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$

but I recognise this as being equivalent to the translation operator $T_x$ acting on $f(y)$ evaluated at $y=0$, since,

$$\exp \left( x \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\right) f(y) \bigg\rvert_{y=0} = f(y+x) \bigg\rvert_{y=0} = f(x).$$

From this perspective, it seems I can always compute $f(x)$ from this series. However, we know the Taylor series need not converge to $f(x)$ for all $x$.

However, this is not immediately obvious from this point of view. What am I missing that tells me that applying the operator $T_x$ and evaluating at $y=0$ will not necessarily give me $f(x)$?

I'm guessing it boils down to showing that $T_xf(y)$ isn't always $f(y+x)$? In other words, is the class of non-analytic functions the same as those for which $T_xf(y) = f(y+x)$ need not hold?

Answer (score 0):

The shift operator $T_a f(x) = f(x+a)$ is always well-defined.

When you write $T_a f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!} a^k=\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!} a^k$ you assume the RHS converges and is well-defined, which is not true in general, not even when [$f$ is smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), not even when [$f$ is analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence).

Similarly, the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{T_h-T_0}{h}$ isn't well-defined on every function space, and $T_0 = \lim_{h \to 0} T_h$ is what defines spaces of continuous functions.

As a (linear) operator on the space of analytic functions with radius of convergence $> a$ then the above series converges and yes $$T_a = \lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n  \frac{a^k}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dx^k}$$

Finally you need to give a precise meaning to $\exp(a \frac{d}{dx})$ and the exponential of linear operators. If it is by the Taylor series of $\exp$ then ..